# unable to generate click event more than once in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
   $('table tbody tr').click(function add_div() {
    if ($('#dynEdit').length > 0) {
        $('#dynEdit').remove();
        return false;
    }
    $(this).after('<div id="dynEdit"></div>');
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/TransJobAddress/EditAddress',
            datatype:'html',
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR)
            {
                $('#dynEdit').html(data);
            },
            error:function( jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                alert('The server saying:' + errorThrown);

            }
        });

});
$('#close').click(function closediv() {
    $('#addrIndex').load('/TransJobAddress/ListAddresses #addrIndex table');

});
```

I am using this in mvc project

By clicking on a row i can insert edit page using ajax this is ok.
When Insert new record using new record button I am replacing table list which is in div tag with Id="addrIndex"

After clicking CANCEL button on new record box it is going back to table list .If I click again on any row second time nothing is working. How can I Edit a row again more that one time after cancel a new record also.

Comment: Are your rows inserted dynamically? Does the div in which the rows are present reload as a result of AJAX calls?

Comment: Yes the Edit inserted dynamically .If click row again it will collapse.If click new record button top of table (not shown in above) it will replace the list with new record with ajax only

Comment: Yes. This is a common thing. Why did you not do a search before posting? Anyway youve got 3 answers. All of them are right. choose one.

Answer (score 1):

delegate your event handler from a parent that's there at the time of binding

```
$(document.body).on('click','tr', function(e) {//...});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when the HTML gets replaced, the elements lose its bindings. Try binding the click in your div.

```
$("#addrIndex").on("click", "table tbody tr", function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

bind click on #addrIndex [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#addrIndex").on('click', 'table tbody tr', function(){
   ///your code here
});
```

Comment: Hi Sushil, I have tried above code .But not worked,and elements are loosing its bindings as above answere.Is there any other way to try?